# How do I stop a bitbucket pipeline from running if the branch is deleted?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Bitbucket's Pipelines can take a while to set up. I have them build on every Pull Request and Branch but by the time they get around to it, the branch can be gone.

I want Bitbucket to fail silently when it cannot find the branch. It doesn't matter to me if it aborts happily if it cannot find the branch. I do not want to receive messages of the following form:

```
Attempt 3 of 6 failed.
Retrying in 4 seconds
Cloning into '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build'...
warning: Could not find remote branch important_assert to clone.
```

Essentially, I would like to edit the "Build Setup" section to prevent Bitbucket from warning me at all in this case.

##### Context for why

If I make an edit to a `README.md` in the repo, I'm not going to hang around to see if the pipeline works. I am going to make the change, someone is going to read it, and then I'm going to merge it before Bitbucket gets around to building it. Once I've merged it, I'm going to delete the branch because it's not of much use to me lying there.